# Check if this is the norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

How to check that such a function on $\mathbb{R}^2 $ $F(x) = \sqrt{2x_{1}^{2} + 3x_{2}^{2}}$ is a norm? I know the conditions of the norm, but I need an example of how to check them.

Comment: Hint: If $T(x_1,x_2)=(\sqrt 2 x_2, \sqrt3  x_2)$ the $F(x)=\|T(x_1,x_2)\|$ .

Comment: What do you think the conditions are? Which one is giving you trouble?

Comment: Ok, so let's start with the first condition: $F(x)=0 \iff x=0$ so it is obvious because $F(0) = 0$, second condition: its ok, but I don't know how to write third condition, do I have to prove that there is such an inequality? $F(x+y) \leq F(x) + F(y) $ and $F(x+y) = \sqrt{2(x_1+y_1)^2 + 3(x_2 + y_2)^2} ?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prove the 3 following properties:

- $||x|| = 0 \iff x = 0$
  Id est, prove that $\sqrt{2x_1^2+3x_2^2} = 0 \iff x_1 = 0 = x_2$.
  *Hint* → Suppose one of the coordinates is non zero, what happens?
- $||x|| \geq 0$
  Can the square root be negative?
- $||x + y|| \leq ||x|| + ||y||$
  *Hint* → Try to reduce the problem to the standard Euclidean norm. As we know that $$\sqrt{(x_1+y_1)^2 + (x_2+ y_2)^2} \leq \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2} + \sqrt{y_1^2 + y_2^2}$$ holds.

> Let $x = (x_1, x_2)$ and $y=(y_1, y_2)$. As we are in $\mathbb{R}$, there exists some numbers, $x_1', x_2', y_1'$ and $y_2'$ such that $x = \left(\frac{x_1'}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{x_2'}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$ and $y = \left(\frac{y_1'}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{y_2'}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$. Plugging in the values, we have $$\sqrt{2\left(\frac{(x_1'+y_1')}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 + 3\left(\frac{(x_2'+y_2')}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2} = \sqrt{(x_1'+y_1')^2 + (x_2'+y_2')^2} \leq \sqrt{2\left(\frac{x_1'}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 + 3\left(\frac{x_2'}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2} + \sqrt{2\left(\frac{y_1'}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 + 3\left(\frac{y_2'}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2} = \sqrt{x_1'^2 + x_2'^2} + \sqrt{y_1'^2 + y_2'^2}$$